# Webscrape Beautifulsoup on website for car prices

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to webscrape this webpage and export in google sheets. Ideally this is coded with a FOR loop to get all the trims (also for some other car/url inputs).
How do I get the Trim and Price in my code? Ideally 1 row per trim

As I just started scraping and coding would higly appreciate your input!

[Desired output and input on website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xh5U3.png)

Output:
 `[<td class="car-sub-model-trim-levels-table__name cb-table__sticky-left"><a href="/cars/tesla/model-3/2022-tesla-model-3" title="2022 Tesla Model 3 Specs">Model 3</a></td>, <td class="car-sub-model-trim-levels-table__name cb-table__sticky-left"><a href="/cars/tesla/model-3/2022-tesla-model-3-long-range" title="2022 Tesla Model 3 Long Range Specs">Long Range</a></td>, <td class="car-sub-model-trim-levels-table__name cb-table__sticky-left"><a href="/cars/tesla/model-3/2022-tesla-model-3-performance" title="2022 Tesla Model 3 Performance Specs">Performance</a></td>]`

Code:

`````
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

#Google Sheets verification
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'keys.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = None
creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = 'PLACEHOLDER'
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
sheet = service.spreadsheets()

#Google sheets header row
sheet_header = [['Trim', 'MSRP']]
request = sheet.values().update(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range="caranddriver!A1", valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body={"values":sheet_header}).execute()

#Inputs/URLs to scrape:
URL2 = ('https://carbuzz.com/cars/tesla/model-3')
(response := requests.get(URL2)).raise_for_status()
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
overview = soup.find()


trim  = overview.find_all(class_='car-sub-model-trim-levels-table__name cb-table__sticky-left')
print(trim)


msrp = ''


data_sheets = [[trim, msrp]]
request = sheet.values().append(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, range="caranddriver!A2", valueInputOption="USER_ENTERED", body={"values":data_sheets}).execute()````
`````

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Pandas. This is perfect for the task you wrote

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('https://carbuzz.com/cars/tesla/model-3')
print(df[0])
```

OUTPUT:

```
          Trim    Engine            Transmission        Drivetrain Price (MSRP)
0      Model 3  Electric  Single Speed Automatic  Rear-Wheel Drive      $46,990
1   Long Range  Electric  Single Speed Automatic   All-Wheel Drive      $57,990
2  Performance  Electric  Single Speed Automatic   All-Wheel Drive      $62,990
```

**UPDATE none pandas solution**:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://carbuzz.com/cars/tesla/model-3'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
for tr in soup.find('tbody').find_all('tr'):
    trim = tr.find('td', {'class': ['car-sub-model-trim-levels-table__name', 'cb-table__sticky-left']}).get_text()
    price = tr.find('td', class_='car-sub-model-trim-levels-table__price').get_text()
    print(trim, price)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Model 3 $46,990
Long Range $57,990
Performance $62,990
```

Comment: I just want the Trim column and Price MSRP column. How do I remove the remaining data points? Thanks

Comment: `print(df[0].to_string(columns=['Trim', 'Price (MSRP)']))`

Comment: @webscrapeartist 
I added a solution without using Pandas, maybe it will be more convenient for you

Comment: this is even better. thank you so much!!!

Comment: quick follow-up questions. I try to do the same on this website: https://www.caranddriver.com/tesla/model-3 any clue how to do this without pandas? Thank you in advance!